# boost::shared_ptr default construction causes member function get to disappear?

Tags: c++, boost

Assume for a second we have

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   boost::shared_ptr<int> bleah(); //default constructor
   cout << bleah.get() << endl; //error line

   boost::shared_ptr<int> barf(new int (10));
   cout << *barf.get() << endl; //outputs 10 as normal.


}
```

How come this does not compile?
It's as if the function shared_ptr::get just all of a sudden disappeared from the class definition for the variable "bleah". 
I'm sure there's a reason, but I cannot see it at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the **[Most vexing Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)** in C++.

With this statement:

```
boost::shared_ptr<int> bleah(); //default constructor
```

You declared a function taking zero arguments that returns a shared_ptr with name `bleah`.

To create an object, change it to:

```
boost::shared_ptr<int> bleah;
```

Comment: Ah. You are correct sir(s). Thanks for your clarification, both Als, and Ylisar.

Answer (score 7):

The first isn't a shared_ptr, it's a function taking zero arguments that returns a shared_ptr with name bleah, remove the ().